# rosbag topics for robot model visualization

Tags: rviz, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to determine which topics are required for robot model visualization in rviz during a rosbag playback.  Any helpful hints about topics and/or nodes that need to be run would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9870/rosbag-topics-for-robot-model-visualization/) by [Travis Deyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/287/travis-deyle/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2011-05-02

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am also wondering the same. I just began with URDF today.
I did not fully explore the urdf documentation, but it did not seem so clear about the minimal configuration you would need to run a simple model without a joint_state_publisher nor a robot_state_publisher. Also, I stay curious about how to deal with partial tf trees, and tf updates from multiple sources when dealing with joint and robot publisher.

Then, I would guess only tf... provided that all the frames of your model are broadcasted by some entity(ies), it should be ok.

It seems from [rviz documentation](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/DisplayTypes/RobotModel) that you only need to load your urdf model as a parameter.

> **Robot Description:** *The parameter to retrieve the urdf
> from. Uses searchParam() to search up
> the parameter tree for the value
> specified.*

For example, in a launch file:

```
<param name="robot_description" textfile="PATH_TO_URDF_FILE" />
```

Should just do it. I can tell you more tomorrow when I will be integrating my brand new urdf model.

Raph

---

Originally posted by [raphael favier](https://answers.ros.org/users/139/raphael-favier/) with karma: 1382 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-02**:
Hi Raphael, you are correct, you only need the `tf` messages and the `robot_description` parameter. However, the easiest way to get `tf` published is to use `joint_state_publisher` (or something else that publishes JointStates) and `robot_state_publisher`.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The minimal configuration to show a URDF model in RViz, independent of whether you run a rosbag playback or not, are:

- the `robot_description` parameter must be set (as Raphael said)
- the `tf` messages for all the frames corresponding to the URDF links

Assuming that your rosbag contains the `tf` messages, all you need to do is set the `robot_description` parameter before starting RViz.

---

Originally posted by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) with karma: 11816 on 2011-05-02

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I finally revisited this issue when building some nice visualizations.  The guys' description above is spot-on.  If you're using the PR2, just run this:

```
rosrun xacro xacro.py `rospack find pr2_description`/robots/pr2.urdf.xacro -o pr2_urdf.xml
```

Then in a launch file (that also plays your bag file with tf messages):

```
<launch>
  <param name="robot_description" command="cat $(find mypackage)/pr2_urdf.xml" />
  <node pkg="rosbag" type="play" name="rosbagplay"
    args="--clock -q -r 1.0 $(find mypackage)/tmp.bag" />
</launch>
```

Works great.  Thanks for the feedback y'all.

---

Originally posted by [Travis Deyle](https://answers.ros.org/users/287/travis-deyle/) with karma: 91 on 2011-05-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2011-05-21**:
You can simplify this even further: